# How to read and use the node label from properties file?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Trying to read and use the node label from properties file as below, I have `hello/world.jenkins` which is my JenkinsFile and `hello/world` file checked-in which has some properties including `NODE_LABEL=my-server-name`, both files are in in git, and I am using `Pipeline script from SCM` definition and `hello/world.jenkins` as Script Path in Jenkins pipeline configuration.

```
def scriptPath = currentBuild.rawBuild.parent.definition.scriptPath // hello/world.jenkins
String fileWithoutExt = scriptPath.take(scriptPath.lastIndexOf('.')) // hello/world
println "props_file=" + fileWithoutExt // prints correctly.

properties = readProperties file: "$fileWithoutExt" // here it fails, I could see hello/world file present in the workspace
echo "node: ${properties.NODE_LABEL}"

pipeline {
    agent { label props1.NODE_LABEL }
    ...
    stages {
      ...
    }
}
```

I cannot load properties file outside of `stage`, is there any other way to read the node name for properties file?

log:

```
props_file=hello/world
[Pipeline] readProperties
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
```

Answer (score 0):

`properties` is not visible as it's not declared as a global environment variable. Do this instead:

```
env.properties = readProperties file: "$fileWithoutExt"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def scriptPath = currentBuild.rawBuild.parent.definition.scriptPath // hello/world.jenkins
String fileWithoutExt = scriptPath.take(scriptPath.lastIndexOf('.')) // hello/world
pipeline {
    environment {
        nodeProp = readProperties file: "${fileWithoutExt}"
        nodeLabel = "$nodeProp.NODE_LABEL"
    }
    agent { label env.nodeLabel }
    ...
```